# Nginx not starting, no feedback

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment

I am deploying a nginx/uwsgi based server on an EC2 instance, and when I go to start up nginx I do not get any feedback.

```
/etc/init.d/nginx start
```

returns nothing

I can confirm that is offline, but it hangs up when I attempt to check the configuration.

```
/etc/init.d/nginx configtest
```

returns

```
 *Testing nginx configuration
```

and nothing else.

I do indeed have a config file located at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf , as well as the core /etc/init.d/nginx file. I can upload either of those if they help.

EDIT: in the nginx error reporting log file 
'[alert] 17644#0: version 1.2.6 (Ubuntu) of nginx.pm is required, but 1.2.6 was found'
I installed this from the simple command

```
 sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
```

Comment: How you install it ? compile, from repos etc, what system you use ?

Comment: I used git to grab it off of unfuddle, then installed requirements with pip (I am new to webdev, and trying to make this as painless as possible)

Comment: '[alert] 17644#0: version 1.2.6 (Ubuntu) of nginx.pm is required, but 1.2.6 was found' 
Was my error message, and this is on a fresh amazon EC2 instance [link]http://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-d183af94--ubuntu-images-ebs-ubuntu-raring-13-04-i386-server-20130423. 
My install consisted of 'sudo apt-get install nginx-extras'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the rc script using e.g.

```
bash -x /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

to see where it fails and proceed from there.

One thing would be the logs, in the worst case use `strace` to start nginx.

Look what a quick copy/paste into Google found out:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1174158

Comment: Ah thank you, your copy paste did indeed help- it was a nginx-extras install error.Installing nginx-full fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

What OS you are using , is /etc/init.d/nginx have all the correct path to start up NGinx on that particular server?

Comment: Using ubuntu, unsure of what you mean all of the correct path, but I have not changed the core nginx file, and my nginx.conf does not seem to need to point anywhere specific for my app. I am using a virtualenv though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new and looking for an easy way to install nginx on ubuntu try:

> sudo apt-get install nginx

You then start nginx like this:

> sudo service nginx start

There are other ways to install nginx (compile yourself from source, or grab it from a more up to date mirror) but if you don't need anything out of the ordinary the above method is the easiest and quickest way to get up and running.